# EF Designer from database - Edit generated models

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using 'EF Designer from database' approach. In my generated models I have a few ICollections that I don't really need. Can I remove those ICollections without breaking stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what they are actually being used for you may be able to remove them without breaking anything, if you know what you are doing.

The problem is, as it is with any auto generated code, that if you make schema changes down the road and need to regenerate your model whatever you have removed will be added back.

Therefore, the recommended approach is to remove the collections that you don't need from your model in the model designer and generate the model without those collections.

Comment: And just like that, they are gone forever. Thank you very much.